# ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute does not take effect in azuredevops pipeline

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, code-coverage

I add some `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` in my class method in order to get the proper code coverage.It works well in visual studio so that I can get the right results.
But we I use a visual studio test in azuredevops pipeline,It does not take any effect.The method which include this attribute appears in Code Coverage result.
I also specify a CodeCoverage.runsettings file in my pipeline,I'm not clear it will effect the result.

```
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - Test Function App Project'
  inputs:
    runSettingsFile: src/DWP.CDA.FunctionApp/DWP.CDA.FunctionApp.Test/CodeCoverage.runsettings
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    diagnosticsEnabled: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's your `runsetting` files look like. But on my side, everything work fine and the classes which configured with `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` are excluded successfully.

Please try with ensuring below script in your runsetting file:

```
 <Attributes>
   <Exclude>
     <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
   </Exclude>
 </Attributes>
```

Here is my compared result between non-exclude and excluded:

[image]